# ROS 2 Mesh file and Pointcloud Matching Package

Tags: ros2, pcl, mesh, pcd, icp

Hi Dear ROS Developers,

I am looking for a ros2 package to take input of my PCD mesh file and compare the PCD with Real-time point-cloud data on the given frame and giving me the center of the object need to be detected.

I am looking for the package like this: [Rail Mesh ICP](https://wiki.ros.org/rail_mesh_icp)